# JDOM Parse XML with Umlauts

Tags: java, jdom, diacritics

I'm trying to get the weather data from googles weather api and parse the document via JDOM.

This is the code I'm using:

```
SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
Document doc;
URL url = new URL(GOOGLE_WEATHER_API);
doc = builder.build(url);       
Element root = doc.getRootElement();
Element weather = root.getChild("weather");
List currentConditions = weather.getChildren("current_conditions");
...
```

Problem is that whenever the XML returned by Google contains an Umlaut (ü, ä, ö...), I get a JDOMParseException

> org.jdom.input.JDOMParseException: Error on line 1 of document http://www.google.de/ig/api?weather=Heidelberg&hl=en:
>   Fatal Error: com.sap.engine.lib.xml.parser.ParserException:
>   Incorrect encoded sequence detected at character (hex) 0x72, (bin) 1110010.
>   Check whether the input parsed contains correctly encoded characters.
>   Encoding used is: 'utf-8'(http://www.google.de/ig/api?weather=Heidelberg&hl=en, row:1, col:191):
>   Incorrect encoded sequence detected at character (hex) 0x72, (bin) 1110010.
>   Check whether the input parsed contains correctly encoded characters.
>   Encoding used is: 'utf-8' (http://www.google.de/ig/api?weather=Heidelberg&hl=en, row:1, col:191)

When I open the URL in a Browser an check the properties of the page the encoding is UTF-8. So I don't know why it does not work.
Does anybody have an idea?

Best regards,
Paul

Comment: Odd, I can't think of anything except maybe to try a different XML parser like Xerces. I don't know about the com.sap.engine.lib.xml.parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xml result from that URL does not include any encoding in its xml header.  Instead the encoding is specified on the Content-Type header of the http response (ISO-8859-1).  Apparently, even though you are passing a URL to jdom, it is not handling this correctly (it is using UTF-8, which is the default for xml with no encoding).  You need to either handle the http response yourself (reading the header and passing the correct encoding to jdom), or use a parser which can do that for you (although i don't know of any standard xml parser which will).

If you used the standard xml APIs, you would do something like:

```
HttpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
String encoding = ... // get encoding from http header
InputSource source = new InputSpource(url.openStream());
source.setEncoding(encoding);
DocumentBuilder db = ... // create doc builder
Document doc = db.parse(source);
```